# Can iOS unit tests be run in milliseconds rather than seconds?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I've been trying quite hard in the past 1.5 years to adopt a test-first process with my iOS development and basically found that two things prohibit me from doing this effectively:

- compilation time — as project sources and test sources both grow (i.e. # source files grows), compilation time grows
- wait for the iOS Simulator to launch — this can be slow as well.

As a result, even if your tests take milliseconds to run, it could take upwards of 5-10s to get feedback from them, simply because there's that magnitude of time spent preparing those tests to be run.

How can this be mitigated?